Combobox & Select Aura Searchable Bar
is there a way to make lightning:combobox or lightning:select searchable, aka have a search bar ? Seems like there is no framework for it and it becomes a huge blocker for people working with aura. lightning:input doesnt have "options" attribute

Check this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297089/searchable-lightningselect-component
